# Bandwidth needed for playing CSGO with a stable ping?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, networking

I am on a 2.6 Mbps (sometimes it goes as high as 3.0 Mpbs) ADSL connection. And no I cannot currently upgrade to anything better unfortunately.

So I have been trying to play CSGO on this connection with mixed success, as I have a decent enough latency/ping. I was "upgraded" to ADSL2+. As I thought the reason why my ping would spike, is because of bandwidth issues, meaning that if the download all of a sudden increased either due to CSGO or background programs, I would get a ping spike.

So I bought a router/modem that can do SNR (signal noise ratio) adjusting to try and increase my speed. And it did, however that only lasted for a few days. And then my connection reset back to around 2.6 Mbps. Interestingly my SNR margin has now gone up after the reset, but I can play CSGO quite well now with 2.6 Mbps. Also I am using G.dmt modulation or old school ADSL. And it seems to give a much better SNR than ADSL2 or ADSL2+, and is seemingly better for playing CSGO.

So is it because my internet connection is perhaps now more stable with a higher SNR and this modulation that I can play?

And what is the minimum connection speed required for one to play CSGO with a constant ping (so that the game runs smoothly)?

Comment: What game mode are you playing? Keep in mind if you are going into private servers, the location of those will also affect your ping.

Comment: I am just playing matchmaking and deathmatch (Valve's version). But I am aware of the fact that the closer one is to the server the lower the ping. Also my problem is not that the ping is too high, the problem is that the ping fluctuates...

Comment: Stability (aka ping) is more important than speed (Mbps). Even having FIOS gigabit is meaningless if it's not a stable connection. Ping is a reflection of how many hops it takes to get from you to the server. Sometimes your ping simply sucks and you need to either get a better ISP or move physically closer to the server. Ping time is typically a lot better during the night when fewer people are using the Internet.

Comment: Sure! But my ping/latency is fine, or the idle ping/latency is fine. But the problem is that the ping/latency is very sensitive to bandwidth usage, because I have so limited bandwidth, for example if a background application starts using bandwidth then it impacts my ping/latency.